# Writing Japanese string to a text file through SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement where i need to write Japanese strings stored in a table to a text file.
I tried below query, its printing only question marks in text file.

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(2000), @Msg NVARCHAR(1000);
SELECT @Msg=String FROM JapaneseStringTable;
SET @cmd='echo '+@Msg+'>>'+'C:\Data\Test.txt';
EXEC sys.xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

I tried to hard code the Japanese string and write to file, still no luck

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(2000),
@Msg NVARCHAR(1000)=N'データノード';
SET @cmd='echo '+@Msg+'>>'+'C:\Data\Test.txt';
EXEC sys.xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

Comment: Declare @cmd as nvarchar as well

Comment: On a different note, i don't know how the value of `@msg` is being passed, but that's looks like a terrifying SQL injection vulnerability. If that value is being passed from some kind of free type field, that's is literally a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Tried it but still not working. I believe this issue is something to do with Unicode text file format. Thanks for replying.

Comment: So, whats the usecase anyways? Maybe it would be an option to use SSIS ?

Comment: Larnu. I also tried to pass the Japanese string which is stored in table to @Msg and write to text file. Its again  printing only ?????

Comment: @VimalRaj No idea what the japanese string is, but varchar + nvarchar = varchar

Comment: John. In general, i am trying to write Japanese characters to a text file through SQL.

Comment: @Tyron78. I need to write log in Japanese to a text file through SQL query or SP.

Comment: Maybe `SET @cmd= N'echo '+@Msg+ N'>>'+ N'C:\Data\Test.txt';`? I still see this and have concerns about vunerabilties mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your OS has a different `code page` than Japanese. So your problem is not related to `SQL Server` that passes Japanese string, but to OS that operates this string as ASCII.

To get the correct result you should change OS codepage in someway.

You can prove it to yourself by using your command directly from cmd:

```
echo データノード >> C:\Data\Test.txt
```

And this will give you ?????

If instead you first change codepage in the same cmd window:

```
chcp 936
```

and then execute your `echo データノード >> C:\Data\Test.txt`

output file will have correct ascii codes.

If you still cannot see them correctly use Word to view this file, but at least there will be no character lost (?????) and ascii codes will be correct.